# OpenERP 5.16 configuration to connect different database

Tags: postgresql, odoo

Need Help,

How to configure a different way of accessing the database in OpenERP?

I have one already installed OpenERP server version 5.16 and the PostgreSQL 9.1, I did a master-slave database replication to another server. so I have three servers, the first one already installed OpenERP and PostgreSQL, the second master replication of postgresql, the third slave replication of postgresql, how do I access a database that has been replicated?

Comment: Do you want to access master and replica at a same time from same instance ?

Comment: thank you for respon, yes, same network, just different database location "db_host", how to config in openerp 5.16? thanks

Comment: thank you for respon, different instance/different machine and in same network